# ckeditor readonly mode only works for text not picture

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

I have set ckeditor to readonly mode, but this will only prevent the text from being edit, yet the picture inserted will still be able to reposition here and there. I want everything inside the editor be disabled. I know ckeditor is using iframe for controls, but I don't have much time to explore all of the nitty kitty of ekditors.

The solution I am using for readonly mode is http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15659 (by Garry Yao).

Answer (score 1):

Current version of ckeditor(3.6) added [setReadOnly](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setReadOnly) function for this purpose it is fine. You can refer to this.

Comment: Dear Abdullah, Thanks for info, I know the latest version has this feature, but due to some compatibility issues I cannot updated to the latest ckeditor instead I have to find some workaround that will have the same functionality in previous (3.5.4) version of ckeditor, I was looking someking of upgrade feature.